# Have they ever published normal-sized Tintin volumes?

Tags: french-language, textual-history, comics, tintin, herge

Have they ever published normal-sized Tintin volumes? The books with 3 in 1, but the size of the single issues.

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean by "normal sized"? The regular size is around 22.5 x 1 x 30.3 cm, one album/story per volume.

Comment: @Tsundoku sorry, The 22.5 x 1 x 30.3 cm (with one story) are what I’m defining as the normal size. I was wondering if they have ever published any 3 in 1s (three storys in one) at that size. Kinda like the compact books but, bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "normal" size of Tintin albums I grew up with in Belgium is around 22.5 x 1 x 30.3 cm, both for the French and the Dutch editions.

However, there have been compact editions that were printed on a smaller size paper. This includes the series "The Adventures of Tintin" published by Egmont in English with a "[trimsize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_trimming)" of 156x221mm.
(These are now in HarperCollins's catalogue; see [HarperCollins to buy Egmont Books UK](https://www.thebookseller.com/news/harpercollins-buy-egmont-books-uk-alongside-poland-and-germany-business-1198696) by Mark Chandler, 1 April 2020.)
I have found the following volumes:

- [Volume 4](https://harpercollins.co.uk/products/the-adventures-of-tintin-volume-4-herge?variant=32610600288334): The Shooting Star, The Secret of the Unicorn, Red Rackham's Treasure (2015),
- [Volume 5](https://harpercollins.co.uk/products/the-adventures-of-tintin-volume-5-herg?variant=32610692530254): The Seven Crystal Balls, Prisoners of the Sun, Land of Black Gold (2015),
- [Volume 6](https://harpercollins.co.uk/products/the-adventures-of-tintin-volume-6-herge?variant=32610703802446): Destination Mood, Explorers on the Moon, The Calculus Affair (2015),
- [Volume 7](https://harpercollins.co.uk/products/the-adventures-of-tintin-volume-7-herge?variant=32610591014990): The Red Sea Sharks, Tintin in Tibet, The Castafiore Emerald (2015),
- [Volume 8](https://harpercollins.co.uk/products/the-adventures-of-tintin-volume-8-herge?variant=32610556182606): Flight 714 to Sydney, Tintin and the Picaros, Tintin and Alph-Art (2015).

I assume the first three volumes are temporarily out of print. (Earlier printings of these three-albums-per-volume editions are listed on Goodreads: see [Volume 1](https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/74602-the-adventures-of-tintin-tintin-in-america-cigars-of-the-pharaoh-th) and [Volume 2](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36545694-the-adventures-of-tintin-vol-2).)
There is also [The Tintin Collection (The Adventures of Tintin – Compact Editions)](https://harpercollins.co.uk/products/the-tintin-collection-the-adventures-of-tintin-compact-editions-herge?variant=32610898346062) in eight volumes in a slipcase, with the volumes having the same trimsize as the individual albums listed above (i.e. 156x220mm).

When scrolling through the [list of albums on Tintin.com](https://boutique.tintin.com/en/livres-et-papeterie-tintin/albums-tintin.html) (the official Tintin website), the only edition with three comics per volume is the slipcased edition mentioned above. All other albums are only available separately.

I am not aware of similar editions in French or Dutch. There was a compact edition in Dutch in the early 2000s, but that edition contained one album per volume, not three.

Comment: Just to clarify, They never combined three volumes in the bigger size?

Comment: @Morgan I can't positively prove that a regular-size three-comics-per-volume edition has never existed, but if it did, the evidence is not readily available on the Web.